# Integrating Adyen in .Net, getting Unauthorized response

Tags: c#, .net, payment, adyen

I am trying to integrate Adyen in a .net application.
Downloaded the sample code from their Github repository and hardcoded the api-key, merchant and client keys in the code to make sure they are getting populated.

Running the code from my localhost

I am getting this error
`{"status":401,"errorCode":"000","message":"HTTP Status Response - Unauthorized","errorType":"security"}`

at this line:
`var res = _checkout.Sessions(sessionsRequest);`

Sample code is here
`https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-dotnet-online-payments`

Any idea of what I am missing?, anyone faced the same issue?
Thanks!

Comment: The error occurs during the `Sessions` call so the issue is with the API key and/or the Merchant account. Can you share some code (without the keys of course) with setting up the `sessionRequest`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, i was able to get successful calls after checking how those keys are set to the environment variables. Also Client key is important.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).